# Editing/scaling rigged model

Tags: mesh, rigging, edit-mode, scale

I have a rigged model that I want to turn into a different body type (I want to make the arms shorter, etc). I scaled the arms and it looks fine, but the rig stays in its original position below the hands. How do I keep the rig attached? It still works, but changing the pose doesn't work normally because the rig is far from the hands/arms... What should I do?

Thank you in advance

Comment: do you mean the bones don't have the good length anymore? Select the armature, go in Edit mode and change their length

Comment: So I need to manually scale both the mesh and the armature seperately?

Comment: Yes, change the mesh, then select the armature, go in Edit mode, enable the X-Axis Mirror option (in T panel > Options in 2.7, in the N panel > Options in 2.8) and move the bones tails so that they align to the new mesh.